# Unable to receive form data in controller in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

I am new to spring mvc framework and I am facing an issue in getting the values from the view in controller.
Please find below the code.

Here is the jsp:

```
<form:form action="envDetails" method="POST" commandName="enviromentForm">
<c:forEach items="${enviromentForm.environments}" varStatus="i" var="env">
        Name of Environment<c:out value="${(i.index)+1}"/>:
       <form:input path="environments[${i.index}].name" type="text"/>
       <br>
       Path of Environment<c:out value="${(i.index)+1}"/>  :
       <form:input path="environments[${i.index}].path" type="text"/>
       <br><br>
</c:forEach>
<input class="submitStyle" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form:form>
```

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="envDetails",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView setBackingForm(HttpServletRequest request) {
    EnviromentForm envf=new EnviromentForm();
    envf.setProjectName("Test");
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
        envf.add(new Enviroment());
    }
    return new ModelAndView("envDetails","enviromentForm",envf);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "envDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView viewFolderInput(
        @ModelAttribute("enviromentForm") EnviromentForm enviromentForm,BindingResult binding,WebRequest request, SessionStatus status) {

    ***//here I am not receiving the values in enviromentForm***
}
```

This is EnviromentForm class:

```
public class EnviromentForm {

private String projectName;
private List<Enviroment> environments;

public EnviromentForm() {
    environments = new ArrayList<>();
}

public EnviromentForm(String projectName, List<Enviroment> environments) {
    this.projectName = projectName;
    this.environments = new ArrayList<>();
    this.environments.addAll(environments);
}

//getter setter

public void add(Enviroment env) {
    this.environments.add(env);
}

}
```

and this is Enviroment class:

```
public class Enviroment {
private String name;
private String path;

//getter setter

}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does the controller method get hit?

Comment: @KevinBowersox yes it does.

Comment: @xtm initialize environments at the time of decleration, remove from no-arg constructor.

Comment: add getters and setters for environments remove add method. Spring default calls to getters and setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that Spring MVC 3.0.1 renders the `<form:input>` tag in the HTML as:

```
<input id="environments0.path" name="environments0.path" value="" type="text">
```

Notice the `name` attribute is missing the brackets (`[]`), which makes it compliant with the HTML specification, but breaks your data binding.  There are two ways to resolve this issue, upgrading Spring or using a regular `input` tag.  I would recommend upgrading Spring.

### Upgrading Spring

The first resolution is to upgrade the projects Spring libraries.  I found the version `3.2.5.RELEASE` sent the parameters across the wire as follows:

[image]

which corrected the parameters from the `3.0.1.RELEASE` as depicted below:

[image]

### Using a Regular HTML Input

The other fix is to use a regular HTML `input` tag to create the form controls and their name attributes.  This will eliminate the modifications `Spring 3.0.1` is making to the `path` attribute (which eventually renders as the `name` attribute).

```
<input name="environments[${i.index}].name" type="text"/>
```

Comment: i replaced every "enviroment" with environment but still not able to figure out.Did u made any other changes ?

Comment: @xtm Did you see my gist linked in my answer?

Comment: Also, you do have a closing `</form:form>` tag right?  It is ommitted from the question.

Comment: Yeah that tag i have in my form. Thing is again I am receiving empty list in the controller method. It is giving me a new object with no values set.

Comment: Well, lets think this through.  I have demonstrated that what you have provided more or less works.  Maybe the issue is outside of the provided code.  Can you put the project somewhere? Or make a Gist with the complete files?  I would be interested in seeing the getters/setters.  I know they are simple but they must meet the bean standard naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Kevin but i think it is the problem with web.xml. When I am using .html as the url pattern and using spring view resolver then again the code u provided is not working. If you want to see my application then please find it here [link](https://github.com/xtm/Local.git) .

Comment: I don't see how your controller is being hit.  Your using `@RequestMapping` but do not have those annotations enabled with `mvc:annotation-driven` in your configuration.

Comment: @xtm I believe I have found a resolution for your issue.  Please see the updated post, thanks for providing the GitHub Repo.

Answer (score 0):

you have misplaced request mapping to `@Controller(value = "/")` instead of `@RequestMapping(value="/")` add it to `EnvController`.

the value element of `@Controller` indicate a suggestion for a logical component name, to be turned into a Spring bean. see more about [@Controller](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html?is-external=true)

Also, why you need of `add()` method, If you want to add Environment to list then add it by calling getter of `environments`

like this:

```
environmentForm.getEnvironments().add(env);
```

Comment: I have getter and setters just removed them for readability. Please find code at [**Application**](https://github.com/xtm/Local.git)

Comment: @xtm you have misplaced request mapping to `@Controller(value = "/")` annotation instead of `@RequestMapping(value="/")` add it.